# How can I use this dropdown logic in more than one <li> element?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a simple dropdown button using react, it's working fine but now I want to use the same logic to use it on Two more buttons.

How can I take the same logic that I'm using in **1st Dropdown menu** and use in the other two

elements **2nd Dropdown menu** and **3rd Dropdown menu** ?

Here is a link that shows the code in action : http://codepen.io/rkhayat/pen/e3581b3625fc6b6f8fa5a8dab2a28a41

Here's my code:

```
class Header extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props) 
        this.state = {
            open:false
    }
}

_handleDropDown(){
    this.setState({
        open: !this.state.open
    })
} 

render() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar">
                    <ul>

                        <li>
                            <div onClick={this._handleDropDown.bind(this)} className="dropdown open">
                            <button className="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle "type="button" > 1st Dropdown menu</button>
                               {
                               this.state.open 
                               ?
                               <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                   <li><a href="#">Adventure Tours</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Airport transfers</a</li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Car rental</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Sightseeing tours</a</li>
                                 </ul>
                                 :
                                 null
                                }
                            </div>  
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">2nd Dropdown menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd Dropdown menu</a></li>                          
                    </ul>
        </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

**Update**:

I came up with a solution that work but I don't know if it's a best practice:

**Here is the code:**

```
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props) 
            this.state = {
              open:false,
              open2:false
          }
      }

 _handle1stDropDown(){
      this.setState({
          open: !this.state.open
      })
  }

  _handle2ndDropDown(){
      this.setState({
          open2: !this.state.open2
      })
  } 

  render() {
      return (
           <nav className="navbar">
                      <ul>
                         <li>
                              <div onClick={this._handle1stDropDown.bind(this)} className="dropdown open">
                              <button className="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle "type="button" > 1st Dropdown menu</button>
                                 {
                                 this.state.open 
                                 ?

                                  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                     <li><a href="#">1st dropdown 1st li</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">1st dropdown 2nd li</a</li>
                                     <li><a href="#">1st dropdown 3rd</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">1st dropdown 4th</a</li>
                                  </ul>

                                  :
                                   null
                                  }
                              </div>  
                          </li>

                          <li>
                              <div onClick={this._handle2ndDropDown.bind(this)} className="dropdown open">
                              <button className="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle "type="button" > 2nd Dropdown menu</button>
                                 {
                                 this.state.open 
                                 ?

                                 <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                     <li><a href="#">2nd dropdown 1st li</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">2nd dropdown 2nd li</a</li>
                                     <li><a href="#">2nd dropdown 3rd li</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">2nd dropdown 4th li</a</li>
                                  </ul>

                                  :
                                   null
                                  }
                              </div>  
                          </li>

                      </ul>
          </nav>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need to do is extract the button and the dropdown into its own component. In order for that to work you would need to make them compossible components meaning that you would pass in the items in the dropdown as props. I made a codepen showing what I mean

http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/ozBxrZ

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
  }

  createItems() {
   return this.props.items.map(function(item, index) {
     return <li> <a href="#"> {item.title} </a></li>
   })
  }

  render() {
    var items = this.createItems();
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.onClick} className="dropdown open">
        <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
          Dropdown
          <span className="caret" />
        </button>
             {
        this.props.open
        ?
            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
            {items}
            </ul>
               :
            null
          }
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

you'd have to customize it to your needs but you can put dropdown anywhere just need to give it the right props

Comment: If I wanted to open the dropdown on hover and not onClick how would I do to achieve that ?

Comment: The way i've handled this in the past is have a `onMouseEnter` and a `onMouseLeave` and just have them toggle the state of the component from being open to closed and vice versa. You just replace the onClick on your div with those two events

Comment: I did put the 'onMouseEnter` on the dropdown button and the `onMouseLeave` on the <ul> element this way the dropdown is closed when the mouse leave. But now if I go from one dropdown btn to the other dropdown btn both dropdown menus appear on the screen. Is there a way to have something like `mouseWentLeft` or `mouseWentRight`so that I toggle the dropDown menu off if the user move the mouse from one dropdown title to the other ?

Comment: can you post the pen of this

Comment: Here is a pen with two dropdowns menu that opens on hover : http://codepen.io/azizCode/pen/dpNQxa?editors=0010

Comment: did you have a chance to have a look at the codepen that I posted in the previous comment  ?

Comment: How i solve this problem in our app, just make the container div what handles mouseout and mouseenter, since your actual dropdown contents is about 10px below the actual trigger container you have to use some css to apply an invisible bottom to the container div that way when you move your mouse down into the dropdown container it doesn't trigger the onmouseleave event and close the dropdown

Comment: I actually didn't understand what you did in order to make it work ? Where do you add the invisible bottom ?